# The joint probability of the random variables $X$ and $Y$ is given by...

Tags: probability, summation

The joint probability of the random variables $X$ and $Y$ is given by
$$P(X=n, Y=m) =\frac{\alpha ^{m}\beta ^{n-m}}{m!(n-m)!}e^{-(\alpha +\beta )} $$
$$m=0,1,2...$$
$$n=m, m+1, m+2, ...$$

Evaluate $P(X=n)$ and $P(Y=m)$.

**My solution so far:** 
$$f_{XY}(n,m) = P(X=n, Y=m)$$
$$P(X=n) = f_{X}(n) = \sum_{m}f_{XY}(n,m) = \sum_{m=0}^{n}\frac{\alpha ^{m}\beta ^{n-m}}{m!(n-m)!}e^{-(\alpha +\beta )}$$
$$=e^{-(\alpha +\beta )}\frac{1}{n!} \sum_{m=0}^{n}\frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!}\beta^{n-m}\alpha^{m}$$
$$=\frac{(\beta+\alpha)^{n}}{e^{(\alpha+\beta)}n!}.$$

Here, I know that the upper limit is not $\infty$, but I'm not sure how to obtain the upper limit. If the upper limit was n, then the format would fall under a common summation formula and result in the last line answer. How do I get the upper limit? Also, am I doing this correctly in general?

For $P(Y=m)$:

$$P(Y=m) = f_{Y}(n) = \sum_{n}f_{XY}(n,m) = \sum_{n=m}^{\infty}\frac{\alpha ^{m}\beta ^{n-m}}{m!(n-m)!}e^{-(\alpha +\beta )}$$
$$=e^{-(\alpha +\beta )}\frac{1}{n!} \sum_{n=m}^{\infty}\frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!}\beta^{n-m}\alpha^{m}$$
$$=?.$$

Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are doing well.

The upper bound is $n$, because the support is $\{(m,n)\in\Bbb N^2:0\leq m\leq n<\infty\}$.

PS: That will also tell you the bounds for the summation in the other marginal pmf.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding why the upper limit is n tho. Like how did you get that?

Comment: $n\in\{m,m+1,m+2,\ldots\}$ means $m\leq n$ @beepboopbeepboop

Comment: HAHA I knew that. Thanks.

Comment: So, the limit for $P(Y=m)$ would be from $n=m$ to $n=\infty$, which causes the sum diverge to infinity. There is no upper limit for n?

Comment: Yes, exactly so. @beepboopbeepboop

Comment: Right, but if that diverges to uninfunity the sum becomes infinity, which isn't right.

Comment: There are values of $\alpha, \beta$ for which it will converge.  @beepboopbeepboop

Comment: Hi @Graham Kemp, I'll be honest and say I have no idea how to solve the summation: $$e^{-(\alpha +\beta )}\frac{1}{n!} \sum_{n=m}^{\infty}\frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!}\beta^{n-m}\alpha^{m}$$. Do you mind showing by step how to solve this? Thanks.